Posts and comment deletion
Do you guys think it is okay to delete posts and answers after they are answered or commented on? I have seen where I see comments related to a reply that does not exist. Comments that relate to another comment that does not exist. It seems to corrupt the threads. There is no real reason to do so. 
Editing of a comment is allowed only if done within 5 minutes or else you have to delete it and re-comment. I do not understand the reason behind it. If you are allowed to delete, you can  surely be allowed to edit.

The SE engine encourages not deleting content in most cases. Do you have a specific example of a thread where there's missing context as a result of deleted comments/posts?

You can see in question http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-to-show-that-this-weak-scheme-is-a-cubature-scheme , TheBridge thanks @stonybrooknick for some comment that is not there any more.

I don't like it, I would prefer it that deletion is only done after a community vote. 

Found one fairly easily. You can see in question http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-to-show-that-this-weak-scheme-is-a-cubature-scheme , TheBridge thanks @stonybrooknick for a comment that is gone

I started off with a comment, but decided to upgrade to an answer.
Deleting posts and comments, even after a question has been resolved, is almost never a good idea. 
Why, you might ask?
Because the purpose of any Stack Exchange site is to create a library of expert knowledge for future generations. It's never just about the asker and the answerer. The goal is to build for the future. 
Deleting posts after a question has received a quality answer degrades the long term usefulness of this site. 
Please don't do it!

I dont frequent SE that much right now. But I will find you some examples where someone has commented that they like that answer but that answer is missing.
